# Is it possible to add redirect (301) inside angular app?

Tags: angular, redirect, angular-router

Let's say my app is running on `domain.com` and most of links in the internet to this site looks like this: `domain.com/:id`.

I want to improve SEO a little bit and add redirects (301):
`domain.com/:id => domain.com/:title`. But to get title for id I have to run angular app and check this in DB.

So what I want to do is:

1. User go to `domain.com/:id`
2. Check `title` for `id` from url inside angular app
3. Redirect user with 301 status to `domain.com/:title`

Answer (score 0):

You have to run Angular using Angular Universal with server-side rendering. There is a guide to get you started, and if it's a new Angular project it's relatively easy to add.

https://angular.io/guide/universal

You then have to tell Express to perform a 301 redirect, and this can be done by configuring the main module used for SSR.

https://gist.github.com/KostyaEsmukov/ce8a6486b2ea596c138770ae393b196f

Answer (score 0):

You can make some changes or by adding a condition in your `server.ts` file.

in the listed code, all routes first come here then the express server(SSR) render the front end angular HTML files. so before sending any response to the browser we can send the 301 status code.
we can add the condition like this

```
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => { 
   // req.originalUrl in this object we can read the requested URL
    if(req.originalUrl == '/old-url-example'){      
        res.redirect(301, 'http://localhost:4000/new-url');
    }else{
        res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
    }
  });
```

You can get more detail on this [article](https://eavnitech.com/blog/how-to-redirect-301-http-in-angular)

Comment: This only works if the page loads from the 1st time or reloading, but not when there is a route change in angular.

Comment: @jcdsr you just can't "make a redirect 301" from the inside of angular app. you can put location.href='new url', but it won't be 301. 301 is made from the server side. if you want to do in both, you have to write that code twice - in the express part as it is shown in the above code, and in your Angular part as well.