# 301 redirect in angular 5

Tags: angular, express, redirect

I am using angular in front-end and returning simple 301 response from node server (Express)

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.redirect(301, 'http://localhost:4200/second')
});
```

And routes i have are:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '',component: HelloComponent},
  {path: 'third',component: ThirdPageComponent},
  {path: 'second',component: SecondPageComponent}
];
```

I am redirecting from http://localhost:4200/third to http://localhost:4200/second, but instead of redirect, I am getting an error (404), but http://localhost:4200/second route is working fine.

Comment: You already have a component for third though?

Comment: Refer https://stackfame.com/301-redirect-node-express Hope this helps!

Comment: @NiallMitch14  if redirects is not happening, I will see that component there, and I don't think it will affect redirect in any way.

Comment: @KrunalShah I don't think it is related to the node coz when I hit that endpoint directly from the browser, redirection is happening.

Comment: @pawanbhatt if you try localhost:4200/test as your URL, does the redirect work then?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653406/is-it-possible-to-add-redirect-301-inside-angular-app

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your code, this is what I did
1. I create a node api with the 301 redirection.
2. I create a new Angular app with your routes.
3. I put a router.navigate on ngOninit to redirect from second to third

I'll let you here the code on my github ,
[app](https://github.com/jordicuevas/stackoverflowredirectsapp) 
[api](https://github.com/jordicuevas/stackoverflowredirectapi)

tell me if that's what your trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts sir, but I don't want redirect from Angular in my case. I want 301-redirect as I need SEO thing. And I don't think there is a way to catch 301 responses in angular. Its browser which performs the 301 redirects. ( Please correct me if I m wrong)

Comment: you can read this answer and see if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653406/is-it-possible-to-add-redirect-301-inside-angular-app

Comment: i tried with SSR, i am not getting a 404 but still the url is not changing, message: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4000/second"
status: 200
url: "http://localhost:4000/second"